# Protractor: How to test an element built with ngTagsInput?

Tags: angularjs, protractor, ng-tags-input

I currently has a simple form that I am trying to test with Protractor. While it seems to work fine with basic input types, it does not seem to work with [ngTagsInput](https://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput) the way I have it set up. I was wondering if there was a particular way of setting this up without triggering the error below.

```
Failed: unknown error: cannot focus element
(Session info: ...)
(Driver info: ...)
...
```

Currently my form, has 4 elements. A name (standard input), a type (radio buttons), targets (the tag inputs), and a submit button. In HTML, it appears something like this.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter name here..." ng-model="name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div id="t1" class="radio">
        <input name="radioType" id="a" value="A" checked="" type="radio" ng-model="type">
    </div>
    <div id="t2" class="radio">
        <input name="radioType" id="b" value="B" type="radio" ng-model="type">
    </div>
    <div id="t3" class="radio">
        <input name="radioType" id="c" value="C" type="radio" ng-model="type">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <tags-input class="btags" name="targets" min-length=1 placeholder="Enter your targets here..." min-tags=1 add-on-blur="true" ng-model="targets">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <button id="submit" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="submitThing()"></button>
</div>
```

Lastly, the one Protractor test I have written looks like this.

```
it('should submit a valid thing',function(){
    //Sets a name for the object
    element(by.model('name')).sendKeys('user');

    //Sets a type for the object
    element(by.id('t1')).click();

    /*Inputting tags (the functions below) seem to not work and throw an error*/

    //Clicks (or focuses on) the tag input box
    element(by.model('targets')).click();

    //Types in the elements within it
    element(by.model('targets')).sendKeys('target1');

    //Presses Enter to submit that particular target
    browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();

    //Repeat for more
    element(by.model('targets')).sendKeys('target2');
    browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();
    element(by.model('targets')).sendKeys('target3');
    browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();
    element(by.id('submit')).click();
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I typed this out instead of copying and pasting. But yes, it is by.model(). I fixed the question details.

Comment: There are not. This is the only thing currently on this page.

Comment: You need to look at the HTML that is rendered and focus on one of those elements. Custom elements are not able to receive focus.

Answer (score 3):

The managed to find a solution thanks to MBielski's comment. It turns out that you need to look at the HTML that is rendered and focus on one of those elements since it is a custom element. Using Google Chrome's developer tools, I managed to find some of the inner code for the make up of the tags. In short, it appears as:

```
<input class="input" ng-model="newTag.text">
```

There is much more information in this inner element, but I left what was relevant. So, you add information into the tags inbox I've defined in the question asked, you would simply focus on the model called "newTag.text", like this.

```
it('should submit a valid thing',function(){
    //Sets a name for the object
    element(by.model('name')).sendKeys('user');

    //Sets a type for the object
    element(by.id('t1')).click();

    //Clicks (or focuses on) the tag input box // This may not be needed
    element(by.model('newTag.text')).click();

    //Types in the elements within it
    element(by.model('newTag.text')).sendKeys('target1');

    //Presses Enter to submit that particular target
    browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();

    //Repeat for more
    element(by.model('newTag.text')).sendKeys('target2');
    browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();
    element(by.model('newTag.text')).sendKeys('target3');
    browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();
    element(by.id('submit')).click();
}
```

This solved the problem for me. Hopefully it also does for others.